# Why do I get an upload error ITMS-90680 and ITMS-90171

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, xcode10

I updated my Mac to Mojave and updated Xcode to 10. I added a WatchKit framework to my project. When I upload my project to the App Store, there are some errors occurring.

> ERROR ITMS-90680: “The binary you uploaded was invalid.”
>
> ERROR ITMS-90171: “Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file
>   ‘XXXX.app/Watch.app/_WatchKitStub/WK’ is not permitted. Your app can’t
>   contain standalone executable or libraries, other than a valid
>   CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle
>   Programming Guide at
>   http://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on
>   the iOS app bundle structure.”

It seems that my WatchKit isn’t in this bundle. Or what should I do after adding WatchKit? I don’t know why I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent two days diagnosing this issue for my own build. There are several possibilities, but they're all related to a resource bundle target:

- If your "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase includes any implementation files (.m or .swift file)
- If your "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase includes any compiled files (.framework, .a, or unix binary files)
- If your "Versioning System" build setting is set to "Apple Generic" (you may need to click "all" on the build settings tab if it doesn't show up under basic)

The latter was my issue